# What word lies between two comparatives?

Tags: word-request

We can get **hotter** and **colder**.

What's a word for staying at the same temperature?

For example:

> Should I turn the heating on? That way I will get **hotter**.
>
> Or should I go and sit in the fridge? That way I will get **colder**.
>
> I think I might stay where I am and (your word goes here).

Comment: Well, I think you must provide more information. Temperature of what? Atmosphere? Food? Drink? any thing?

Comment: does it matter?

Comment: Of course yes, see there -I wrote 'room temperature' and there's a comment with an exception. If you are talking about hot/cold water, it's then room temperature as a neutral temperature. And so goes true with any food

Comment: lots of things can get hotter and colder, but what if their temperature remains constant?

Comment: I think of a few words: uniform/constant/stable/normal/regular

Comment: @DavidWashington; true - but these aren't specific to temperature

Comment: The temperature remains 'constant' and it is a very general word. I'm sure that you *know* this. Your 'lots of things' should be specified to have a specific word for it. This is the reason, I'm telling that it is unclear.

Comment: The word has to be _specific_ to temperature? This is hard! If you could add some context to the question, illustrating the situation where you want to use such a word, that might help the answerers quite a bit.

Comment: Processes that develop on a constant temperature are *isothermal*. This is a technical term and really isn’t applied to people so I’m not sure it fits the example in OP’s question (but then, it is a rather peculiar example).

Comment: You could provide a (possibly facetious) verb for what you were going to do anyway if nobody suggested a change.  For example, "suffer", "relax", "chill out", "broil", "bake", "sweat", "freeze", "read", "work", "write", *et cetera*.

Comment: @MaulikV "Room temperature" is only the neutral value between "hotter" and "colder" if you assume that the temperature started out at room temperature. OP is asking for a word meaning for the temperature to remain the same. What if it's already very hot or very cold? "Wow, it's freezing here. We should light a fire to make it warmer." vs "Wow, it's freezing here. If we don't do something it will X", where X means "remain the same temperature". (I don't think there's any such word.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a single word, but you could say "The temperature remained constant."

Answer (score 1):

Then you use the plain form of the adjective. If the temperature is already high, then you could say, "If I stay where I am, it will remain hot." If the temperature is already low, you would say, "It will remain cold." Likewise you could use whatever word is appropriate for the current temperature: warm, cool, broiling, freezing, lukewarm, comfortable, whatever.

I don't know a single word that means "the temperature is the same as it was before". You'd have to use several words for that, like, "The temperature will be unchanged" or "it will remain the same temperature". If it's obvious from context that you're talking about temperature, then you could just say "it will be the same" or "unchanged" or "constant", etc.

Similar things could be said about other comparative words. "Al is taller than Bob" or "Al is shorter than Bob", but there's no single word I can think of that you could fill into "Al is X than Bob" that means "is the same height". Normally we'd say "Al is the same height as Bob" or something similar.